# Swapless distances

Tags: code-golf, string

Suppose you have a string \$s_0\$ and someone else has a hidden string \$s_1\$.  You don't know what \$s_1\$ is but they tell you that they can get from your string, \$s_0\$, to their string by making a certain number of moves \$d\$.  Each move can be one of the following:

- Insertion : Add a character anywhere in the string
- Deletion : Remove a character from anywhere in the string
- Replacement : Replace one character with another anywhere in the string
- Transposition : swap any two adjacent characters.

(this is [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)).

The question is how many moves do you need to get from \$s_0\$ to \$s_1\$ *without using the transposition move* (this is [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance))?

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a string (list of positive integers is fine too) representing \$s_0\$ and a positive integer representing \$d\$ and output the minimal number of moves required to guarantee you can get to \$s_1\$ without transposition in the worst-case scenario.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) your answer will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

## Test cases

### Using Strings

```
"Hello", 3 -> 4
"World", 2 -> 4
"aaaaa", 1 -> 1
"aaaaa", 2 -> 2
"abaaa", 3 -> 4
"Krypyp", 3 -> 5
"", 5 -> 5
"Hello", 0 -> 0
```

### Using Integer lists

```
[1,2,3,3,4], 3 -> 5
[1,2,3,4,5], 2 -> 4
[1,1,1,1,1], 1 -> 1
[1,1,1,1,1], 2 -> 2
[1,2,1,1,1], 3 -> 4
[1,2,3,4,3,4], 3 -> 4
[], 5 -> 5
[1,2,3,3,4], 0 -> 0
```

Comment: It took a while to puzzle out, but I think this is asking for the largest Levenshtein distance among all strings with a given Damerau-Levenshtein distance from a given string.

Comment: @Nitrodon Yep that's another way to say it.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance from `Hello` to `Hleol` is 3, so the example test case would need to be something based on `eHlol` instead.  As for the length 6 test case, a distance of 5 is possible (e.g., `rrKyypp`)

Comment: Actually, `Hello` and `eaHlol` have Levenshtein distance 4: `Hello` → `HeHlo` → `eHlo` → `eHlol` → `eaHlol`

Comment: I couldn't find any string that shows `"Hello", 3 -> 5`. Are you sure it's 5? Otherwise my solution is wrong.

Comment: @japh I'm not really sure.  I am a little busy at the moment so I'll edit it down to 4.  I'll take a look at it later.

Comment: Suggest testcase `"abbaab", 3` (should be 5, maybe)

Comment: Suggest testcase `"Hello", 0`, should be 0.

Comment: @tsh `"abbaab", 3` results in `4`

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 186 bytes

```hs
-- f :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
f s k|let a=pure<$>0:s;d#(x:z)|let w(y:z)|d>0=[y:x:z];w _=[]=[c++y++z|c<-[]:a,y<-[]:[[x]]]++w z++map(x:)(d#z);_#_=a;d%i=iterate((++)<*>((d#)=<<))[s]!!i=[i|i<-[k..],all(`elem`0%i)$1%k]!!0
```

Simple brute force solution. `f` takes a list of positive integers, and the DL-distance `k`.

This generates all strings up to the DL-distance limit `k`, and searches for the smallest L-distance that contains all of those strings (also by generating those strings). This saves bytes by using the same generator code for both types of distances.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Ra4MwEMff9ymutIVkSYvV9kWN73sY@wAh2KDpFkxdMY5W8bPP3dwYFpY7yP3vl/sfedO@Ms6N4wk8VIMzLWhx@WhMusqC2Cflktzink7gSrrvsswCIbsY2yq5Qi6kErJgrGOsH4p0I1WseTfdUt6UUoxdoWfsrC9oRUm57GmSL3Ohk3JthW1No1tDCGM0fcwIcirSlFLp1WJhhbSDRbNqu1VcO0eOxpnzMVhbutqtK3wSjGdtaxCAC55zuDS2bkEC8XEsn@pWcag4kOl7HPy7qymFATH/05BuQD4AHiJ3POQRxh7nQg4R5Xdgzw8/YD8Dv4Fgh/kvwIlwboWtaG6C@oBJJ6nU@FmcnH714@Yl/AI) Note that this is too slow for some of the test cases, so the TIO version uses reduced test cases.

#### Pregolfed

Ungolfed version. Unlike the golfed version, this one removes duplicate strings during the generation, so it's also much faster:

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

snub x = S.toList $ S.fromList x

f' s k =
  let -- 0 = any other symbol not in s
      alphabet = snub $ toEnum 0 : s
      -- all strings with L-distance 1 (if d, DL-distance)
      gen1 d s@(x:xs) = snub $ del ++ ins ++ sub ++ swap xs ++ map (x:) (gen1 d xs)
        where del = [xs]
              ins = map (:s) alphabet
              sub = map (:xs) alphabet
              swap (y:ys) | d = [y:x:ys]
              swap _ = []
      gen1 _ _ = map (:[]) alphabet
      -- as gen1, but distance <= i
      genAll d i = iterate (\x->snub $ x ++ (gen1 d =<< x)) [s] !! i
      -- strings with DL-distance <= k
      sDL = S.fromAscList $ genAll True k
  in head [ (i, worstStrings)
          | -- sL = genAll False i
            -- zip obtains sL' = genAll False (i-1) for calculating worstStrings
            ((_, sL'), (i, sL))
              <- zip <*> tail $ (,) <*> (S.fromAscList . genAll False) <$> [max 0(k-1)..],
            -- require that sL covers sDL
            sDL `S.isSubsetOf` sL,
            -- also show some maximal examples
            let interestingness t = length (filter (==toEnum 0) t) + abs (length t - length s)
                worstStrings =
                  take 5 $ sortBy (comparing interestingness) $
                  S.toList (sL `S.intersection` sDL `S.difference` sL')
            ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNj9MwEL33VzxWK2GzacWCuFTNCtDChaI9lFuJdt3G2Vp1Psi4NEX8dsrYSbtNF@FL4vGb92bG41kpWmtr93uTV2Xt8GOjrMmMTnGrnBrNtIMizAbdcTBODTkI4v3Hneyd3NUpxLLMK1Wb4lEOBlRsFmgQYzZyZfC75N@sLvOwaQaD7CUIa8QDwLLYcIjXDFfFDqVb6Rq0yxelRVE6mALEML@UrVZqwfgYQeISrvxUbHJ2Hh9BzKWsBTkfDGFr3ArTYcrCqlhqXEOYDGmE2yej7FwfdXGNFPReNOOG5JNMqi2urjgU8h9im/9sVYUmWHL@Yx8J0VGwd8cJbDkhHShizBtKjgft8qRxyzBmzUOOZyiveUA1/4H5mMRuvGPIb46DFXfjhrfJv4D3/jw5Tf4@2FqZefJMxteWAjLCYuNwrOokhnni@cD1T2GYyThdK6chvjfDm66Yja/YoVDxZIJGSswpwYsXRxIW6l3gyWV5rXUHo9tp6DLfWh9o2bVaF8G3eqMDkjtopVWKOV99hG1Zk5u15PKkKr@DqOfr/D8rS/oY0TGuX6ZCuXDK3xtNX57jhRleS2RljaWyy41VjoV6oj1CIe4jTyOjEBxNpTy7qUkrOXl1Axa1nJ@IZNiKfuKjXiAMubzBPFcNXos1xzQaJdF5LrX@sTHcnG6lnM99Wf7UNfmy9pC@zA@zkaHZZkHa3WUPDH5GxqolaFVuQWWuuYkakysL3ai8srqftn/0puDm0OTrU2gi@GdtdfHI1y0yY/kQIo4PL1zCSVxBLQiiQ/HcODjQedXQK3kYNOfLqbXGO65nO9NORth5aBKX//A/DjdBbXm8E@mlM2XxcKhZarKMqbhvH8I193iSfc5t1D64r/eoWNv5LqUI6wjtjPTvOBik74R58BcXK57e5UWEtzLqLJyuTdny5mhRfrHl@pnlBLNoLQee4VBcfKl31a7qkfPmXRt6kuz/LDOrHmk/vHvzFw) This uses the full testcases but `Krypyp` still times out on TIO (it takes a few minutes to solve). Also, it prints some of the strings that have maximal Levenshtein distance. Testcase solutions:

```
"hello", 3 -> 4 e.g. "eeeol","eehol","eeool","ehheo","ehhho"
"world", 2 -> 4 e.g. "owrdl"
"aaaaa", 1 -> 1 e.g. "_aaaa","a_aaa","aa_aa","aaa_a","aaaa"
"aaaaa", 2 -> 2 e.g. "__aaa","_a_aa","_aa_a","_aaa","_aaa_"
"abaaa", 3 -> 4 e.g. "aabbb","aab_b","aabb_","_aabab","_aabba"
"Krypyp", 3 -> 5 e.g. "rKyKppy","rKyppKy","rKyppry","rpKyppy","r_Kyppy"
"", 5 -> 5 e.g. "_____"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, <s>790</s> <s>764</s> 760 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;t->n->{var S=new HashSet<String>();int m=n;for(;m>0;)p(S,"",t+"x".repeat(m--));for(var s:(HashSet<String>)S.clone())for(m=s.length()-n;m-->1;)S.add(s.substring(m));S.removeIf(s->d(1,s,t)!=n);for(var s:S)m=Math.max(d(0,s,t),m);return m;}void p(Set S,String p,String s){int l=s.length(),i=0;if(l<1)S.add(p);for(;i<l;)p(S,p+s.charAt(i),s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i));}int d(int f,String s,String t){int l=s.length()+1,L=t.length()+1,d[][]=new int[l][L],i=l,j,c,q,A,B;for(;i-->0;)d[i][0]=i;for(j=0;++j<L;)for(d[i=0][j]=j;++i<l;B=t.charAt(j-1),c=A==B?0:1,d[i][j]=q=Math.min(Math.min(d[i-1][j]+1,d[i][j-1]+1),d[i-1][j-1]+c),d[i][j]=f>0&i>1&j>1&&A==t.charAt(j-2)&s.charAt(i-2)==B?Math.min(q,d[i-2][j-2]+c):q)A=s.charAt(i-1);return d[l-1][L-1];}
```

Will golf it down (substantially I hope) from here.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVTNjpswEL7vU7gcIrsYFlL10CVQZQ/VrpqVKnHogXJw@NmYGkOwk260ynUfoI/YF0nHhKRsWhUJMz/fzDcztqnYljlV/v3A67bpNKpAdzeaC/dtgND1NfrCwNqUSK8KtNzpwsmajdQI2/6HXlfkKhNMKfTAuHy@QqMM5UZmmjfS/TQIs1h3XD7S/2LupS4ei46iQYgiVKLwoJ1IOtHzlnUoDmXxA90xtYoLPeSMMAk41FWHMiibDgd15AWkxTG1LKpt68lyu6ItmMa14xDSY0wudYMvEpHYzUQjC0yIAdWhckUhH/UKE0cGEB35AWBYnmPlqs1S9WG4hqQxcNTNtrgvsXKiHPtUUU3ehHLMF5M6fGB65dbsCefY6zG0JkFX6E0nUR3sg23DcwTFFxrF9FgXak@CIs@mUzEqjPLQC3iJxcwfSmuPlAGfieMYWlu52Yp1c405oePKPcqJPTbYNodm9oYkx2Ytz9QnQf9dg@3TRajHap6kSdrvFWATkSaLFAoVtKIZXdM5vR1KhJHCXuUJTxMvDXlvraAh265mi6DfBXCGXppUaViB2TR1C1xDP5XjE5qF8zC8/ejdGF7eQ9fDnLnEZwF8jm@89gkHqg3xJ4dRM3LOUUbehEf@pIJ3Agwj0imZ/BkpaIb@zLPuE05NwqlJeLMm83AE98/7nSfCEC9gCfYHhNrNUvAMKc00fPqTUMPVwsfJJylixFwzhODuaWzdFUI0Fn1HgpHxa9OJ3KLTV0ZmHov6/zJeIJe98XXOz92u3bWXVou@vwiF2OUlaijS6437K1jG7fWY8wkz50oOLcY7pYvabTbabcGthcTWN8uylQ0fxGSOLFvaFvr18tNIcNLMXwgTt3RZ24odVmQQJBm494ff)

#### Explanation:

**General approach:**

Input-String = `t` and input-integer = `n` in the explanation below.

1. Generate all permutations of `t` with up to `n` added characters, and add them to a Set
2. For each permutation, add a substring with up to `n` removed characters to the Set as well
3. Remove any String from this Set that does not have a Damerau-Levenshtein distance of `n` in comparison to `t`
4. Calculate the Levenshtein distance of each remaining String in comparison to `t`
5. Take the maximum, which is our result

**Code explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*;               // Required import for the Set and HashSet

t->n->{                           // Method with String and integer parameters and integer return-type
  var S=new HashSet<String>();    //  Create a String-Set
  int m=n;for(;m>1;)              //  Loop `m` in the range [input-integer, 0):
    p(S,"",t                      //   Determine all permutations of the input-String
      +"x".repeat(m--));          //   With up to `m` additional "x" added
  for(var s:(HashSet<String>)S.clone())
                                  //  Loop over all generated permutations:
    for(m=s.length()-n;m-->1;)    //   Inner loop `m` in the range [permutation-length - input-integer, 1]:
      S.add(s.substring(m));      //    Add the permutation with the first `m` characters removed to the Set as well
                                  //  (NOTE: After these loops, `m` is 0 which we'll re-use later on)
  S.removeIf(s->                  //  Now remove any permutation from this Set which:
     d(1,s,t)!=n);                //   Does not have a DL-distance equal to the input-integer
  for(var s:S)                    //  Loop over all remaining Strings:
    m=Math.max(d(0,s,t),m);       //   Determine the maximum L-distance
  return m;}                      //  And return that maximum L-distance as result

// Separated recursive method to get all permutations from a String
void p(Set S,String p,String s){  // Method with Set and two String parameters and no return-type
int l=s.length(),                 //  Get the length of the input-String `s`
    i=0;                          //  Index-integer `i`, starting at 0
if(l<1)                           //  If the length is 0:
  S.add(p);                       //   Add the prefix-String `p` to the Set
for(;i<l;)                        //  Loop `i` in the range [0, length):
  p(S,p+s.charAt(i),              //   Append the `i`'th character to the prefix-String `p`
    s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i));}
                                  //   Remove the `i`'th character from the String `s`
                                  //   And do a recursive call

// Separated method to determine the DL or L distance of two Strings
int d(int f,String s,String t){   // Method with integer and two String parameters and String return-type
  int l=s.length()+1,             //  Length `l` of the source-String + 1
      L=t.length()+1,             //  Length `L` of the target-String + 1
      d[][]=new int[l][L],        //  Create an integer matrix of those dimensions
      i=l,j,                      //  Index-integers
      c,q,A,B;                    //  Temp integers
  for(;i-->0;)                    //  Loop `i` in the range (`l`, 0]:
    d[i][0]=i;                    //   Set the `i,0`'th cell to `i` in the matrix
  for(j=0;++j<L;)                 //  Loop `j` in the range [0, `L`):
    for(d[i=0][j]=j;              //   Set the `0,j`'th cell to `j` in the matrix
        ++i<l                     //   Inner loop `i` in the range [0, `l`):
        ;                         //     After every iteration:
         B=t.charAt(j-1),         //      Set `B` to the `j-1`'th character of the target-String
         c=A==B?                  //      If the characters `A` and `B` are the same:
            0                     //       Set `c` to 0
           :                      //      Else:
            1,                    //       Set `c` to 1
         d[i][j]=                 //      Set the `i,j`'th value to:
           q=Math.min(            //       The minimum of:
              Math.min(           //        The minimum of:
                d[i-1][j]+1,      //         The `i-1,j`'th value + 1
                d[i][j-1]+1),     //         And the `i,j-1`'th value + 1
              d[i-1][j-1]+c),     //        And the `i-1,j-1`'th value + `c`
         d[i][j]=                 //      Then, set the `i,j`'th value to:
                 f>0              //       If the given DL-flag is 1
                 &i>1&j>1         //       And both `i` and `j` are at least 2
                 &&A              //       And the character `A`
                   ==t.charAt(j-2)//       equals the `j-2`'th character in the target-String
                 &s.charAt(i-2)   //       And the `i-2`'th character in the source-String
                  ==B?            //       equals the character `B`:
                  Math.min(       //        Set the `i,j`'th value to the minimum of:
                   q,             //         The `i,j`'th value
                   d[i-2][j-2]+c) //         And the `i-2,j-2`'th value + `c`
                 :                //       Else (the given DL-flag is 0):
                  q)              //        Leave the `i,j`'th value the same
      A=s.charAt(i-1);            //    Set `A` to the `i-1`'th character of the source-String
  return d[l-1][L-l];}            //  Return the `l-1,L-1`'th value as result
```